# Java duplicates distinct unique array value

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this, but i don't know how...

```
Values[10] = {1,1,4,4,2,3,3,2,1,3}
```

to print:

```
{1,2,3,4} or {1,4,2,3} (not sorted, any order, but distinct)
```

I also need to count the number of times each number has occurred, both without sort, new arrays or boolean methods or other data structures, please advise as i am stuck.

Is there a simple method i can use to just print the unique values/ distinct values ?

Comment: are there any bounds on the range of the integers in the array?

Comment: Also, please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  People on SO are willing to help, but you cannot ask us to do your work for you.  You must post what you have already done and ask a _specific_ question, not "please solve this for me".  If this is homework (it looks like it) and you have no idea where to start, then SO is the wrong place to look because it is not a tutorial or discussion site.  Ask your professor or teaching assistant first.

Comment: are there any methods i can use to just reveal distinct values...?

Comment: If you just want the distinct values, then shove it into a `Set`.

Comment: I guess you do something before save value to an array, it could be quite easy for u to use Set <Integer> instead of array. Set<T> is obviously contains a unique value

Comment: hope this doesn't make it harder but it also said not to use other data structures... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be accomplished if your are willing to destroy your current array. and you assume that the array is either of type Integer (so nullable) or if not there is some bound such as all int are poistive so you can use `-1`.

```
for(int i = 0;  i < values.length; i++){               //for entire array             

    Integer currVal = values[i];                       // select current value
    int count = 1;                                     // and set count to 1

    if(currVal != null){                               // if value not seen

        for( int j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++){   // for rest of array
            if(values[j] == currVal){                  // if same as current Value 
                values[j] = null;                      // mark as seen
                count++;                               // and count it 
            } 
        }
        System.out.print("Number : "  + currVal + "  Count : " + count + "\n");
                                                       //print information
    }
                                                       // if seen skip.
}
```

In plain english, Go through the array in 2 loops, roughly O(n^2) time. 
Go to index i. If index has not yet been seen (is not null) then go through the rest of array, mark any indexs with same value as seen (make it null) and increment count varable. At end of loop print value and count. If Index has be seen (is null) skip and go to next index. At end of both loops all values will be left null.

```
Input : Values[] = {1,1,4,4,2,3,3,2,1,3}


Output : Values[] = {1,null,4,null,2,3,null,null,null,null}
          Number : 1 Count : 3
          Number : 4 Count : 2
          Number : 2 Count : 2
          Number : 3 Count : 3
```

Edit: corrected my mistake in output, pointed out by commenters.

Comment: I think this is probably the only way to do this within the (very odd) constraints of this question.

I'm fairly certain there is no possible way to do what he wants non-destructively.

As a side note, as written this won't actually null the entire array. Your inner array never nulls the current vale, so the first occurrence of each value will be non-null.

The actual final array would be `{1,null,4,null,2,3,null,null,null,null}`.

Comment: The output array won't all be null.  The initial values will be left. `[1, null, 4, null, 2, 3, null, null, null, null]`

Comment: You could also use `values[j] = -currVal` and you wouldn't lose any info in the array.  You could get the count (for each positive number, sum its negatives and divide by the number) and maybe print in the order the OP wanted.

Comment: yup this is probably the only way to do it..., thanks gbtimmon :D

Comment: @davidfmatheson / Charles: you are both correct, I have fixed my out put. And good point david, If we have a bound on ints to say they are only positive we can make it non destructive by simple marking seens items as negative. I did not think of that :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, without creating additional objects:

```
Arrays.sort(values);
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || value[i] != value[i-1]) {
        System.out.println(values[i]);
    }
}
```

And the shortest solution I can think of:

```
Integer[] values = {1,1,4,4,2,3,3,2,1,3};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));
System.out.println(set);
```

Comment: he mentions in a comment that he couldnt sort either.

Comment: To be fair, he mentioned that in a comment to an answer that got deleted.

Comment: Perfectly fair... I cant defend how poorly the question was asked.

Comment: @gbtimmon I don't think that what he really wants can be achieved :)

Comment: I think my answer did a fair job. It lists all unique items and counts without sorting and without creating new memory in O(n^2) time.  The two caveats are it is destructive and it does not sort the output.

Comment: @gbtimmon your answer doesn't display the numbers sorted. That was a requirement, too.

Comment: I dont think it was... his example happened to be sorted but he never actually said it was a requirment :P, when i was in college and did all the programming competitions they used to do this kind of stuff in questions all the time. Make all the example answers sorted, but never say it needed to be sorted, so I am pretty sensitive to those kind of things. Also with an incrementing outter loop I can make it sorted in O(n^2 * |range of ints|) time. But that would be a pretty shitty algorithm run time wise.

Comment: @gbtimmon *Values[10] = {1,1,4,4,2,3,3,2,1,3} to print {1,2,3,4}* the first array isn't sorted, while the second is. It didn't happened to be sorted :)

Comment: @gbtimmon I don't think there's any way your solution can print both sorted and the counts together in the manner OP wants. That being said, it's far more efficient than my answer.

Comment: @Charles I think there is a O(n^2) solution that satisfies all his requirements: for every iteration calculate the next min and then count the number of appearances.

Comment: That's exactly what my solution does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are guaranteed to be integers, you could also do it by incrementing a check value, scan over the array, sum the number of that check value in the array, add it to an accumulator and loop while the accumulator < array.length.

Something like this (untested):

```
public void checkArray(int[] toCheck) {
    int currentNum = 0;
    int currentCount = 0;
    int totalSeen = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<toCheck.length; i++) {
        min = Math.min(toCheck[i], min);
        max = Math.max(toCheck[i], max);
    }

    System.out.print("{ ");
    for(currentNum = min; currentNum < max; currentNum++) {
        for(int i=0; i<toCheck.length; i++) {
            if(toCheck[i] == currentNum) currentCount++;
        } 

        if(currentCount != 0) {
            if(currentNum == min) System.out.print(currentCount + "(" +currentCount+ ")");
            else System.out.print(", " + currentCount + " (" +currentCount+ ")");
        }
        totalSeen += currentCount;
        currentCount = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(" }");
}
```

It should be noted that while this technically fulfills all your requirements, it will be *far* less efficient than gbtimmon's approach.

If your ints were `{1,2,3,150000}`, for example, it will needlessly spin over all the values between 4 and 149999.

Edit: added better limits from tbitof's suggestion.

Comment: +1 but if one of the values is Integer.MAX_VALUE... Or worse, a negative value...

Comment: @tibtof Yep. There aren't a whole lot of easier ways to do it, given the requirements though. If you wanted to use libraries, it would be much faster. Stick everything in the while loop in an indexOf != -1 check, for example.

And I could have done it without the StringBuilder, that's just for pretty printing. You could also just print the values within each while, and remove the StringBuilder entirely.

Comment: You can use System.print() instead of StringBuilder. Aloso, may be a little optimized by computing min and max before staring the while.

Comment: @tibtof It could definitely be optimized more. This was just a PoC I whipped up in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear to me, since it sounds like you want to do these things without creating any additional objects at all. But if it's just about not creating another array, you could use a `Map<Integer, Integer>`, where the key is the number from your original array, and the value is the count of times you've seen it. Then at the end you can look up the count for all numbers, and print out all the keys by using `Map.keyset()`

Edit: For example:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for( int i : values ) {
    if( counts.containsKey(i) ) {
        counts.put(i, counts.get(i) + 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(i, 1);
    }
}

// get the set of unique keys
Set uniqueInts = counts.keyset();
```

Comment: Is there a simple method i can use to just reveal the unique value, distinct values ?

Comment: The `keyset` will by definition be distinct. So you would iterate over your array and increment the value (or initialize it to 1 if it's not already in the `Map`. I will edit this to add some sample code.